# A particular word or sentence to descibe a situation

Tags: single-word-requests

**Background:**

A company has clear-cut tasks designed for efficiency, but some tasks are ambiguous. One can either accept a task or not; that is, another will do it, and that's fine on all sides.

However, no one wants to take uninteresting tasks, and everyone is already occupied with routine work.

Does English have a concise word or sentence to explain a situation in which no one wants to accept such a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could use [take a back seat](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-a-back-seat):

> to choose not to be in a position of responsibility in an organization or activity

---

A few other closely related options could be:

[pass the buck](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pass-the-buck):

> to blame someone or make them responsible for a problem that you
>   should deal with

[wash your hands of something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wash-your-hands-of-sth):

> If you wash your hands of something that you were previously
>   responsible for, you intentionally stop being involved in it or
>   connected with it in any way

[the elephant in the room](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/elephant-in-the-room):

> an obvious problem that no one wants to discuss

Comment: Perhaps also something that can be used often, like 'an unwanted task'?